# Como construir um Layout Complex no JSF2?

Tags: jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Preciso aplicar um tipo de Layout no meu sistema de maneira que fique o mais parecido com sistema de desktop, então procurei uns modelo de layout no site do PrimeFaces no site abaixo;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/element.xhtml

E como vocês podem ver existem vários modelo de layout, porém o único que significativamente explica como fazer é o FULL, como mostra abaixo;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/full.xhtml

Porém existe um em especifico que me chamou a atenção que é o layout   " Complex ", quando eu clico é direcionado para está pagina;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/complex.xhtml

Mas essa pagina não mostra como criar o layout, como faço para saber como construir esse layout?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="main/css/showcase.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="main/css/sh.css" />
        
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-layout-north {
                z-index:20 !important;
                overflow:visible !important;;
            }

            .ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
                overflow:visible !important;
            }
        </style>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true" >
                <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" size="50">

                    <p:menubar>
                        <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon-document">
                            <p:submenu label="New" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                                <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Other" url="#" />
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:menuitem value="Open" url="#" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />
                        </p:submenu>

                        <p:submenu label="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
                            <p:menuitem value="Undo" url="#" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w"></p:menuitem>
                            <p:menuitem value="Redo" url="#" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e"></p:menuitem>
                        </p:submenu>

                        <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon-help">
                            <p:menuitem value="Contents" url="#" />
                            <p:submenu label="Search" icon="ui-icon-search">
                                <p:submenu label="Text">
                                    <p:menuitem value="Workspace" url="#" />
                                </p:submenu>
                                <p:menuitem value="File" url="#" />
                            </p:submenu>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menubar>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="bottom" position="south" size="60">
                    Bottom Content
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" size="300" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" minSize="200">
                    <p:accordionPanel>
                        <p:tab title="Menu 1">
                            <br />
                            <p:calendar mode="inline" navigator="none"/>
                            <br />
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab title="Menu 2">
                            <h:outputText value="Menu 2 Content" />
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab title="Menu 3">
                            <h:outputText value="Menu 3 Content" />
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:accordionPanel>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="right" position="east" size="250" header="Gallery" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"
                              style="text-align:center">

                    <p:lightBox style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px;">
                        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" title="Nature 1" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" width="150"/>
                        </h:outputLink>

                        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/demo/images/nature/nature2.jpg" title="Nature 2" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
                            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature2.jpg" width="150"/>
                        </h:outputLink>

                        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/demo/images/nature/nature3.jpg" title="Nature 3" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
                            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature3.jpg" width="150"/>
                        </h:outputLink>

                        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/demo/images/nature/nature4.jpg" title="Nature 4" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
                            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature4.jpg" width="150"/>
                        </h:outputLink>
                    </p:lightBox>

                    <p:commandButton value="Show Dialog" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" type="button" style="margin-top:10px"/>

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

            <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">
                <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
            </p:dialog>
            
            <script language="javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/main/js/sh.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript">
                SyntaxHighlighter.all();
            </script>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>
    
    
</html>
```

Segue o link com o código do layout complex, [aqui](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/showcase/trunk/src/main/webapp/ui/panel/layout/complex.xhtml?r=11205).